# MetaMask cannot connect to "localhost 8545"

Tags: metamask, testrpc, testnets, ropsten, connections

When I choose `localhost 8545` in MetaMask, apparently it is not able to connect. Please see screen shot:

[image]

[image]

I tried with several internet connection, however the same result.

Whereas, I can easily connect to ex. `Ropsten`.

**Do I need to run `testRPC` before connecting to `localhost 8545` ?**

Comment: I has the same issue, swap some BNB to ETH and My ETH appeared in localhost8545, how I can recuperate? When I try to connect to localhost shows a message that's unavailable. I must to run testrpc? How and where I must to do it? Please, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to run testRPC before connecting Metamask. Check the port that testRPC is using as well it should be 8545